# How send data from python on pc to esp32 running micropython?

Tags: python, communication, pyserial, esp32, micropython

Can anyone please explain how to transmit data from python on pc to micropython on esp32 ? Here is my code and i have been at it for the last three days ! Data goes the other way though - from esp32 to pc.
Similar code with appropriate modifications work on microbit !

On the PC side:

```
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial(
  port='COM8', 
  baudrate = 115200,
  parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
  stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
  bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
  timeout=1)

while True:
    
    msg = input()
    ser.write(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    print(ser.readline())
    time.sleep(.1)
```

On the ESP32 side:

```
from machine import Pin, PWM, UART #type: ignore
import time
led=Pin(2,Pin.OUT)
uart = UART(0, 115200)
uart.init()
while True:
    if uart.any():
        msg = uart.read()
        print(msg)
```

Comment: Your PC code is waiting to read something, but you're not sending anything.  You need a `uart.write("hello\n")` in there after the read.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. It still does snot work

Comment: How do you know it works going the other way?  Remember, if you have the debug monitor attached to the UART, then your Python code can't open the file.

Comment: I know because I obtained random numbers in the micropython code and received them  on the serial monitor on the pc side.

Comment: OK, but that means both ends of your UART are attached to the serial monitor.  Your Python code cannot open COM8 because it is already in use by the serial monitor.  You either need to stop the serial monitor or invent a second UART.

Comment: My python code does open the serial port as I had closed the serial monitor on the micropython side before starting the python code to receive the random numbers from micropython.

Comment: I wish to add that the similar code ( with appropriate modifications ) is runs on micro:bit V2

Comment: No, I have taken care to close the shell on one side. It works with other controller boards like the uno and microbit